# SharePoint Online Remove Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Our O365 tenant is not using the current SharePoint site collection **https://companyname.sharepoint.com** - at this stage we have only a couple of O365 groups and a couple of different site collections in use.

I would like to remove the existing site collection **https://companyname.sharepoint.com** and recreate it with a different template, I would go ahead and do something like this:

```
New-SPOSite -Url https://companyname.sharepoint.com -Owner Admin -Title "Company Name" -StorageQuota 1000 -LocaleID 1033 -ResourceQuota 300 -Template "STS#3" -TimeZoneId 17 -CompatibilityLevel 15
```

Will the deletion of **https://companyname.sharepoint.com** destory anything else like the existing O365 groups and/or existing site collections? Will my O365 tenant loose any functionality and/or availability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deletion of you "root" site collection will not remove sites located on other locations like "/sites/sitea", "/teams/team1" but **it will remove** subsites located under the root site collection.

Other site collections will stop working during the period that you dont have a root site collection.

Comment: i believe in your answer, just out of curiosity, have you done this before?